# Does opening a picture in a temporary filesystem leave any traces with Eye of GNOME/eog?

Tags: mount, encryption, gnupg, privacy, eog

Does the Gnome package *eog* leave any thumbnails or other privacy leaking information when opening a picture in a different filesystem?

I know that thumbnails are created by default in the home directory of the user but is this also the case when using for example a temporary file system in RAM?

My goal is to mount a tmpfs and copy an encrypted archive to the filesystem where I am going to decrypt it to be able to view pictures, videos and texts without them being saved somewhere else and when I am finished I would just unmount the filesystem and reboot. Then every trace should be gone (at least in theory). Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

I would use *eog*, *vlc* and *nano* for these tasks and encrypt/decrypt with *GnuPG*.

Comment: What does this have to do with the unstated Ubuntu OS you are using?

Comment: I thought this is OS-specific (I am using the 20.04 LTS version) and that eog which comes with the standard installation of Ubuntu behaves differently from how a gnome installation on another distro would behave. Alright, I guess I'll move this question to a broader Linux forum then. Thanks for the reply @David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that thumbnails are created by default in the home directory of the user but is this also the case when using for example a temporary file system in RAM?

Yes. And they will not be automatically removed when the temporary file system is removed.